# getting bad request while using passport in login form

Tags: node.js, express, passport-local

I am trying to create a user login [.ejs file] form using passport local session in nodejs. My problem is that I keep on getting bad request when I hit on the submit button,can anyone please check my code and help me out

Here is my nodejs code:

required:

```
var express = require('express');   
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = express();
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 'secret'
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

passport:

```
var user = mongoose.model('val', Schema);
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        passReqToCallback: true
    },
    function (firstName, password12, done) {
        console.log("entered Function");
        user.findOne({
                firstName: firstName
            },
            function (err, firstName) {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err);
                }
                if (!firstName) {
                    console.log('User Not Found  ' + firstName);
                }
                if (!isValidPassword(firstName, password12)) {
                    console.log('Invalid Password');
                } else {
                    console.log('correct');
                    return done(null, firstName);
                }
            }
        );
    }));
```

login page:

```
app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.render('login');
});
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function (req, res){
    var userInfo = req.body;
});
```

Comment: Bad request is when your sent request is mismatched with the expected request.
so please add code for both sides.

Comment: the code for login.ejs is also been added now

Comment: did you try removing `app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.render('login');
});` this code?

Comment: nope but with out that how will we access the login.ejs file,I don't think it's possible

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have posted partial Nodejs file code? Where is the code for the authenticate function that you call at

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function (req, res) {
    var userInfo = req.body;
});
```

In addition to authenticate method, you need passport.serializeUser and passport.deserializeUser methods. Passport invokes these 2 functions and they are needed.

Here is the demo code. Do write your own code keeping this as reference

```
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(user.Id); // the user id that you have in the session
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    done({id: Id}); // generally this is done against user database as validation
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
passReqToCallback: true
```

if you use this, than add **req** to code. next line should be:

```
function (req, firstName, password12, done) {
```

---

your post router must be something like this:

```
app.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```